# How to find if a post with custom_field == X exists?

Tags: customization, database, mysql, wp-query, query

I need to find if a post with a custom field X equal to Y exists in a wordpress installation.

Should I do it with a simple sql query or is there something build in that can help me achieve it?

Comment: You can do this either at the PHP or SQL level. How against JOINs are you? Or perhaps more appropriately, how big is your data?

Comment: I expect to have about 40 to 80k posts, each one with a custom field that would be like an unique ID and will help me to not create duplicated posts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)(); to check that like this:

```
$my_query = new WP_Query();
$my_query->query(array( 'meta_key' => 'X', 'meta_value' => 'Y'));
if ( $my_query->have_posts() ){

     //it exists

} else {
    //it's not here
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: That looks good, but which files do I need to include to use it? Because I need to use it from a .php that will run as cronjob, not from inside a plugin admin panel or something like that.

Comment: @Rocxy this will require good chunk of WP core. Most compatible would be to use [WP-Cron](http://codex.wordpress.org/Category:WP-Cron_Functions) to run it inside WP, otherwise see [how to load WP core in external code](http://codex.wordpress.org/Integrating_WordPress_with_Your_Website).

Comment: you can wrap in in a function and return a Boolean true or false if the post exists and add this to your plugin file.

Comment: WP-Cron is no good for this case because the cronjob does some really extensive tasks and AFAIK wp-cron add the load time of the cron to the website. I will see if I can load WPCore.

Comment: add `post_type` to the query for custom post types

Answer (score 1):

The current way would be something like this:

```
$posts = get_posts(array(
    'meta_key' => 'color',
    'meta_value' => 'blue',
));

if( !empty($posts) ) { // some posts found }
```

Just note that in upcoming 3.1 querying for custom fields is considerably improved and arguments change, see [Custom Field Parameters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts#Custom_Field_Parameters) in Codex.

Comment: Same question as for the other answers, which files should I include to use this from a stand-alone php file that would run as cronjob?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use this externally(per your comments), to keep the operation cheap you could do something like this.

```
<?php
// You'll need to make sure the path is correct here
include_once 'wp-config.php';
include_once 'wp-includes/wp-db.php';

// Of course update the following line with a more appropriate query
$result = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts"); 

print '<pre>';
print_r( $result ); // Remove and do whatever you need to do
print '</pre>';
?>
```

Loading `wp-config.php` and `wp-db.php` should be enough to call upon the `$wpdb` methods to query the DB for whatever data you need.

Let me know if you need an example SQL query to fetch posts based on meta.

Comment: Cheaper still would be to just use `mysql_query` directly, but you'd then have to deal with opening and closing the connections yourself, etc...